# ckeditor integration with jquery ui tabs

Tags: php, ckeditor

I note that ckeditor has some limitation on integrating with jquery ui tabs.

http://cheaper.com.hk/admin/test.php?id=1

we can see that the editor is loaded in all 3 tabs, but the editing function as well as most of the toolbar icons were disabled in tab2 and 3.

How to initiate the normal functions in tab2 and 3 when shifting among the tabs?

Comment: does each instance have its own name? This is no different than having several copies of ckeditor on one page. oh and i see no ckeditor on the url you posted

Comment: it's the ckeditor inline function, if you click on the text, the editor will come out!

Comment: when mouseover on the editor, I can see 3 different names of instance, so I believe that there are already having their own name.

Comment: one more point. I have created a double click function on the tabs, so that when double click, the page reloads with the selected tab language, and at this circumstance, the editor under this tab works, but others still not okay.

Comment: That demo works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of elements have same id.

All elements must have unique id.

If you used an initializer probably thats why they can't get activated

Comment: I have changed the code so that now there's no repeated id in the same page, at this stage, how can I initialize the editors in tab2 and 3? Thanks.